# BIS setting http headers

Tags: cookies, blackberry

I'm trying to perform a web call which requires a cookie.
Currently I am able to login and get the cookie from the `Set-Cookie` response header.
I then put this in the following requests' header under `Cookie`.

This is working perfectly on WiFi. But as soon as I try with BIS, I get the cookie but the following calls fail.
I have noticed the headers are lowercase for BIS, so I have to get the `set-cookie` field, but how do I use that cookie in the subsequent calls?

I have also tried setting `x-rim-transcode-content: none` with no luck.

I assume I'm just missing some small "feature" of blackberry that would resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a fix for my problem. Extra cookies where being added to the `set-cookie` header, once I stripped them out it worked.